# Suppose a sequence $\{a_j\}$ has the property that, for every natural number $N$, there is a $j_N$ such that $a_{j_N}=a_{j_{N+1}}=\dots=a_{j_{N+N}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose a sequence $\{a_j\}$ has the property that, for every natural number $N$, there is a $j_N$ such that $a_{j_N} = a_{j_{N+1}} = \dots = a_{j_{N+N}}$. In other words, the sequence has an arbitrarily long repetitive strings. Does it follow that the sequence converges?

I am having trouble determining what the sequences look like. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example: $1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,\dots$

Does this sequence converge?

Comment: I would say it does not...

Comment: That's correct.